# Permission denied error while trying to run wget for owncloud

Tags: permissions, wget

I got a permission denied error running the command below:

```
ubuntu@P1-AppServer:/var/www/html$ wget https://download.owncloud.com/server/stable/owncloud-complete-latest.tar.bz2
--2023-10-07 15:22:05--  https://download.owncloud.com/server/stable/owncloud-complete-latest.tar.bz2
Resolving download.owncloud.com (download.owncloud.com)... 167.233.14.167, 2a01:4f8:1c1d:3d1::1
Connecting to download.owncloud.com (download.owncloud.com)|167.233.14.167|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 76290404 (73M) [application/x-bzip2]
owncloud-complete-latest.tar.bz2: Permission denied
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the website root directory to download files. Use your own Downloads directory.

Basically your user 'ubuntu' does not have permissions to save in /var/www/html/ and it should not. That is for the webserver user.

Do

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://download.owncloud.com/server/stable/owncloud-complete-latest.tar.bz2
```

and then check on what to do with the tar file (there will be a readme). Generally I would assume you need to extract it and then copy the files to a location and change the owner to the webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

By default `/var/www/html` is owned by `root:root` with permissions `755`. Your user `ubuntu` have no permissions to write to that directory and that's why you cannot download the file there.

- The best solution is to download the file to another location and then move it to `/var/www/html`.
- Or if you want, you can change `/var/www/html` owner:

  ```
  sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html
  ```

It really depends on what you are planning to do. But if you don't understand how permissions work... better go read a bit about that before doing something stupid.

Edit: btw once you have installed `owncloud`, you will probably have to change the owner of the directory to `www-data` if you run your web server with the default user.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this.

Comment: No to method 2: That will mess up the website that is active unless that is set to 'ubuntu" and it is not(or there would be no permisions error)

Comment: This worked, thanks.